# jquery calculation formatting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

this is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name^=sum]').keyup(function() {
        var sum0 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum0]').val()) || 0;
        var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val()) || 0;
        $('#act_rate').val(sum1/sum0);
    });
});
```

This little script calculates the actual exchange rate from 2 input fields. I would like to display the act_rate with no more than 8 decimal places like 1.12345678. How can I format the outcome like that?

Many thanks for your help in advance. 
Peter

Comment: I tried but it didn't do anything. I did it like this: $('#act_rate').val(sum1/sum0).toFixed(8); and included jquery.field.js or do I miss something?

Comment: You're trying to use `.toFixed` on the jQuery object returned by `.val()`, not on the number itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

```
var num = (sum0) ? sum1/sum0 : 0; // don't divide by zero
$('#act_rate').val(num.toFixed(8));
```

Or, if you want 8 decimal places *or less*:

```
$('#act_rate').val(+num.toFixed(8));  // convert string into number
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/WNXSA/

Comment: Thank you. Obviously my syntax was not ok. I mark this as an answer as soon as the 5 mins run out :)